# DNS not working on Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome, dns, ping, wireshark, nslookup

Yesterday, my internet stopped working. I can't access the internet via IE/Chrome, but Firefox still works. I have resetted Winsock. Ping via name doesn't work either, but with ip it still works. Doing a NSLookup of something like google.com does give the right IP, and I can still browse using this IP. The strangest thing is that Firefox still works. I have checked my settings, and no proxy is configured. I have also done some sniffing using Wireshark, and when I ping google.com, it does send a request to 8.8.8.8 and it gets a valid response with the correct IP (just like nslookup). However, ping (and IE/Chrome) still says that it can't find the host (google.com).

Does anyone know this problem? I have searched for two days, but I can't seem to find the answer on the internet. I want to make sure I have tried everything before I reinstall my Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling my Windows.

DebboR